# How can I put my image in a circle without it coming out on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with an ImageView, I would like to put this image in a circle that contains only a border with the transparent inside so that the image takes up all the space, but without leaving the circle.
What is currently not working! The image goes beyond the circle and I'd like to fix it! Do you have any idea?

This is my circle :

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="@color/colorRedLogoDark"/>
<corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
```

This is my ImageView :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_about"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/thermometer"
    android:background="@drawable/background_about"
    />
```

It's possible or I have to got a round image ?

**EDIT : Actually, I would like to got an image with a border-radius in color !**

Comment: Have a look at frescolib, it's an image library that has already implemented some rounding image that could help you to a faster development.

Comment: Do you want to see the rectangular image inside the circle or are you trying to mask/crop the wnole thing like this: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: I would like to put the rectangle image inside the circle yes ! But I don't want to see the image go outside the circle !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several approaches to tackle this.**

1- You can wrap your image in a card view and adjust the corners to look like a circle. The padding in that case will act as a border
To achieve a circular shape using Card view you can set the shape property, `android:shape="ring"`.
`app:cardCornerRadius` should be set to half the width or height of the ImageView

2- Use a library that does exactly that such as [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

3- [Crop your image through java](http://%E2%80%9CImageview%20customization%20(circular%20image%20view)%E2%80%9D%20by%20MicroPyramid%20https://link.medium.com/9W4vTWyniT)

Answer (score 1):

I would like you to modify your background_abtout.xml file and simply add this lines of code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
android:width="6dp"
android:color="@color/colorRedLogoDark"/>
```

I think this will work perfectly fine